# Move back to previous activity from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity where when the user presses the back button, it closes the application.

To try and resolve this issue I have tried:

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    onBackPressed();

}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, betaEventsActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is that this does not work well. It just takes the user to a specify activity, and not necessarily goes back to the previous activity.

I have also tried:

```
@Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//***Change Here***
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

but this simply closes the application.

Below is my FragmentActivity code:

```
public class usermatch extends FragmentActivity {
    private PageAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private FeedbackDialog feedBack;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        initialisePaging();
        feedBack = new FeedbackDialog(this, "id");


    }

    private void initialisePaging() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment4.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment5.class.getName()));



        mPagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//***Change Here***
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code of the activity you are trying to go back to. Also, did you open the fragment activity from the activity you're trying to go back to?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The issue is that user can arrive this fragment activity from a variety of activity, so I can't just redirect it to a particular activity, just move it back to the last known location

Answer (score 2):

Try with out overridding onBackPressed().

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. unfortunately this not resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Override OnBackPressed method & set the pager to previous item, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the
        // system to handle the Back button.
        // This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.

        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        pager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}
```